# Where to place shower curtain rod in relation to the tub?

Tags: bathroom, shower, mounting

I am not asking how high to mount the shower curtain rod (that is easy to determine from an existing shower curtain).  I am trying to figure out how far "into" the tub it should be mounted.  I want the curtain to not be in the way when showering but still have the bottom edge inside the tub.

I see a few possibilities, what the pros and cons of the following options:

- Line it up with the inside of the tub but that seems like it will be prone to "billowing in" when showering.
- I could line it up over the outside edge of tub.
- Center it over the tub curb.
- Put it "outside" of the tub completely

Comment: This is purely an aesthetics question.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a standard practice though?

Comment: Why?  Its aesthetic.

Comment: I would at least like to know where most people have their rods mounted. I will be mounting this through a tempered glass panel so I need to tell the glass company where to cut the hole before it goes in. I cannot just eyeball it when the time comes to mount it. If you think there is no "right" answer maybe make it a community-wiki, I just want to know what other people do in thsi situation.

Comment: Disagree with this closure. I am facing the same problem planning my shower curtain. It is not aesthetics at all. Placement must be planned correctly to achieve the proper function of the curtain.

Answer (score 6):

My preference is to line it up with either the outside edge or center of the tub so any decorative curtain outside the shower hangs nicely. The waterproof curtain on the inside can just be draped over the inside edge of the tub, and this gives you more space in the shower.

Answer (score 1):

I always position it over the outside edge of the bath, or an inch further out. You can then place a single layer shower curtain inside the tub easily, and if you do have an outer layer, as @BMitch says, it will hang without any bumps.